# How to calculate Cross Variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, cross-variation

Let $B$ be a BM. Let $X_t:=2B_t$ and $Y_t:=B_t^2-t$. Compute $\langle X \rangle_t$, $\langle Y \rangle _t$ and $\langle X,Y \rangle _t$.

For the first and second, it's
$$\langle X \rangle _t= \langle \int_0^t2dB_s \rangle _t = \int_0^t 4 ds=4t$$
and

$$\langle Y \rangle _t=\langle \int_0^t 2B_s dB_s\rangle_t=\int_0^t4B_s^2ds$$

I'm not sure of what I have to do to get $\langle X,Y \rangle _t $

Comment: Polarisation: $\langle X,Y\rangle_t=\frac14(\langle X+Y\rangle_t-\langle X-Y\rangle_t)$.

Comment: Would it also work with $\langle X, Y \rangle _t = \frac{1}{2}(\langle X+Y \rangle _t - \langle X \rangle _t - \langle Y \rangle _t)$ ?